# http requests with Kotlin multiplatform for desktop

Tags: kotlin, httprequest, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm new to kotlin multiplatform and I'm using compose for desktop, how can I make HTTP requests?
is there any resources to learn from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ktor is the best supported multiplatform HTTP client currently, as it is maintained by Jetbrains There are also projects that put together many open source tools for kotlin multiplatform such as: [AAkira](https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries)

There is not a specific place currently that goes over HTTP communication, as it would be specific per tool you choose.

Comment: thank you so much, I used it and it's working.